# Identity check if another user is authenticated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

How I can check with Microsoft Identity if another user is authenticated by his id? There is some function in-build like UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).IsAuthenticated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your authentication works. If you have some central session store somewhere, you could check if that user has a valid session.

If you are not using sessions (for example when using token based authentication), then it's impossible to check if another user is authenticated as that depends on the state of that user's token.

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions

is a part of

> Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core

Then you can use

```
UserManagerExtensions.FindById()
```

You also have the asynchronous method in case you need it which you can access

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userid);
```

Comment: Please note I need to check is authenticated of another user, not my identity. FindById doesn't have any extension for IsAuthenticated